# Which version of Parse-server and mongodb driver at minimum should I use for support of MongoDB 4.2?

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server, mongodb-atlas

I am currently with Parse-server 2.8.4 and mongo driver 3.1.0 to support a mongoDB 4.0 cluster hosted on MongoDB Atlas.

It was announced that my cluster would be automatically upgraded to mongoDB 4.2 by Atlas.

I am wondering if the Parse-server 2.8.4 supports mongoDB 4.2? If not, which version of Parse-server and mongo driver should I use?

I am hesitant to upgrade to Parse-server 3.0 as my web app is in production and it is said upgrading from Parse 2 to 3 requires a significant amount of change.

Comment: I think you will really have to upgrade to the latest version in order to run with Mongo 4.2. The biggest changes are in the cloud code functions. Here you can find a guide: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/3.0.0.md

Comment: Thanks @DaviMacêdo. I have only upgrade the mongodb cluster to 4.2.2 but left Parse as 2.8.4. It seems it works well with mongo 4.2.2. Is this expected?

Comment: I am not sure since there is no automated tests in the CI against 4.2 but you can try to pull the release and run the tests to make sure everything is working fine.

Comment: @alextc were you able to confirm whether Parse 2.8.4 works with mongoDB 4.2? Thanks!